# How to rotate material icon in flutter without animation?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I want the icon `details` to point upward like as shown in the image.
but the list of material icon has icon `details` points to downward, 
so how can I rotate the material icon in my flutter project, without downloading the icon image.

[image]

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 48,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFFBBC05),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                blurRadius: 16,
                offset: Offset(0, 8),
                color: Color(0XFFFBBC05),
                spreadRadius: -10)
          ]),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.details,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: null,
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 8,
    ),
    Text(
      "Historical",
      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'AirbnbCerealMedium', fontSize: 12),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Transform.rotate(
  angle: 180 * pi / 180,
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.details,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    onPressed: null,
  ),
),
```

Comment: `180 * pi / 180` is equal to `pi`

Comment: why do we need angle to multiply by pi/180

Comment: @akshaybhange Because it needs to convert from degrees to radians (measure of unit for circle/rotation)

Comment: With `import 'dart:math' as math;` and using `angle: 180 * pi / 180,` triggered the error: `Error: The getter 'pi' isn't defined for the class` **BUT** it worked fine with  `angle: 180 * math.pi / 180,` ("math.pi" instead of "pi").

Comment: @MarkGavagan if u import dart:math without an alias (as math) it will work as above

Answer (score 75):

You can wrap your `IconButton` in a `Transform` widget using the [rotate constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.rotate.html):

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

Transform.rotate(
  angle: 180 * math.pi / 180,
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.details,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    onPressed: null,
  ),
),
```

Comment: what do I need to import for `math`

Comment: import 'dart:math'

Comment: For this example, it would be `import 'dart:math' as math;`

Answer (score 63):

Another solution is:

```dart
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 2,
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.details,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    onPressed: null,
  ),
),
```

Comment: I think rotated box is a better approach

Comment: I agree! If all you are looking for is to rotate some widget, this is the best answer!

Comment: best one , love it.

Comment: best but, it will not work properly with `leading: ...`, for leading icon it shows margin at start, but still Thank You!!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to rotate icons like arrow_forward_ios, could help following code.

```
icon: Transform.rotate(
       angle: 90 *math.pi /180,
       child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
       color: Colors.white,size: 18,),,
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to use the `Transform` widget.

```dart
Column(children: <Widget>[
  Container(
    height: 48,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFBBC05),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 16,
              offset: Offset(0, 8),
              color: Color(0XFFFBBC05),
              spreadRadius: -10)
        ]),
    child: Transform( //<--- This changed
        transform: Matrix4.rotationX(90),
        child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.details), onPressed: () {})),
  ),
  SizedBox(
    height: 8,
  ),
  Text(
    "Historical",
    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'AirbnbCerealMedium', fontSize: 12),
  ),
])
```

Comment: the icon disappears, I think `Matrix4.rotationX(90)` this needs to be something else